# How to set the upload size in apache commons upload

Tags: java, apache-commons-fileupload

Hi am using apache commons upload for uploading files

```
   File file=this.getFile();//getter method for the file
   String fileName="test.zip";
   File target=new File("D:\\test",target);
   FileUtils.copyFile(file,target);
```

But with this i can upload only upto 20MB.how can i set the size for the uploaded files in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in the [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html). All you have to do is call:

```
// Create a new file upload handler
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

// Set overall request size constraint
upload.setSizeMax(yourMaxRequestSize);

// Parse the request
List /* FileItem */ items = upload.parseRequest(request);
```

The above is from sample code available via the link. However, I don't know of a `FileUtils` class within [Apache Commons Upload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/index.html), and I suspect you may actually be talking about a different library.. There *is* a class called [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) in Commons IO which looks like it relates to your code sample a little better, were you by any chance talking about Commons IO and *copying* a file, rather than *uploading* one?